# Почему эта анимация маски SVG прерывистая в Firefox, но плавная в Chrome?

Tags: html, css, svg, анимация, css-animation

Я упростил анимацию SVG, над которой я работаю (которая должна выглядеть как заполнение контейнера), до примера ниже, который работает плавно в Chrome, но прерывисто / заикается в Firefox. Это SVG с тремя слоями:

Первый слой - это `<mask>` для последнего слоя, который представляет собой красный кружок. Средний слой SVG - это серый круг. Таким образом, красный кружок находится поверх серого круга и становится видимым благодаря маске, которая анимируется с помощью CSS:

```css
#color-mask {
  fill: white;
}

#color-mask path {
  animation: waves .75s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes waves {
  from {
    transform: translateX(17rem);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-17rem);
  }
}

#color-mask g {
  animation: raise 6s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes raise {
  from {
    transform: translateY(11rem);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-18rem);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
    <mask id="color-mask">
        <g>
            <path d="m 909.1,353.4 0,-67.6 c -70.8,0 -106.9,-14.7 -141.7,-29 -34.9,-14.3 -71,-29 -142.1,-29 -71,0 -107.2,14.8 -142.1,29 -34.8,14.2 -70.9,29 -141.7,29 -70.8,0 -106.9,-14.7 -141.7,-29 -34.9,-14.3 -71,-29 -142.1,-29 -71.1,0 -107.2,14.8 -142.1,29 -34.8,14.2 -70.9,29 -141.7,29 -70.8,0 -106.9,-14.7 -141.7,-29 -34.9,-14.3 -71,-29 -142.1,-29 l 0,632.2 1419,0 z"/>
        </g>
    </mask>
    <g id="grey">
        <circle  id="top_grey" style="fill: rgb(180, 180, 180);" cx="200" cy="200" r="200"></circle>
    </g>
    <g id="color" mask="url(#color-mask)">
        <circle id="top_color" style="fill: rgb(196, 3, 3);" cx="200" cy="200" r="200"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

CSS-анимация translates (смещает)  как по горизонтали, так и по вертикали, но с разной скоростью.

Я также пробовал использовать `<clipPath>` вместо `<mask>` и получил те же результаты, такие же прерывистые  аннимации в Firefox в Windows и Linux.

Одна очень странная особенность, которую я заметил в Firefox, заключается в том, что если у меня открыты инструменты разработчика, анимация иногда будет работать плавно. Инструменты разработчика Firefox тоже, похоже, не указывают на какие-либо проблемы, но я не эксперт в SVG-анимации. Почему Firefox подавляется этим, а Chrome - нет?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Why is this SVG mask animation choppy in Firefox but smooth in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62578638/7394871) от участника  [@j08691](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616443/j08691).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62578638/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Другая идея с использованием маски CSS, где у вас не будет проблемы. Я использовал путь, указанный вами, как маску. Просто убедитесь, что вы установили правильное значение для viewBox

```css
.box {
  display:inline-flex;
  width:300px;
  background: rgb(180, 180, 180);
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box:after {
  content:"";
  padding-top:100%;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0%;
  width:200%;
  height:30%;
  bottom:-10%;
  background:rgb(196, 3, 3);
  -webkit-mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="-500 0 1100 900"><path d="m 909.1,353.4 0,-67.6 c -70.8,0 -106.9,-14.7 -141.7,-29 -34.9,-14.3 -71,-29 -142.1,-29 -71,0 -107.2,14.8 -142.1,29 -34.8,14.2 -70.9,29 -141.7,29 -70.8,0 -106.9,-14.7 -141.7,-29 -34.9,-14.3 -71,-29 -142.1,-29 -71.1,0 -107.2,14.8 -142.1,29 -34.8,14.2 -70.9,29 -141.7,29 -70.8,0 -106.9,-14.7 -141.7,-29 -34.9,-14.3 -71,-29 -142.1,-29 l 0,632.2 1419,0 z"/></svg>') top/100% auto;
          mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="-500 0 1200 900"><path d="m 909.1,353.4 0,-67.6 c -70.8,0 -106.9,-14.7 -141.7,-29 -34.9,-14.3 -71,-29 -142.1,-29 -71,0 -107.2,14.8 -142.1,29 -34.8,14.2 -70.9,29 -141.7,29 -70.8,0 -106.9,-14.7 -141.7,-29 -34.9,-14.3 -71,-29 -142.1,-29 -71.1,0 -107.2,14.8 -142.1,29 -34.8,14.2 -70.9,29 -141.7,29 -70.8,0 -106.9,-14.7 -141.7,-29 -34.9,-14.3 -71,-29 -142.1,-29 l 0,632.2 1419,0 z"/></svg>') top/100% auto; 
   animation:raise 6s infinite ease-in-out alternate,waves .75s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes waves {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
@keyframes raise {
  to {
    height:160%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="box" style="width:200px;">
</div>
```

Чтобы использовать только `transformation`, вы можете добавить дополнительный элемент:

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  display:inline-block;
  background: rgb(180, 180, 180);
  border-radius:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box div {
  padding-top:100%;
  position:relative;    
  animation: raise 6s infinite ease-in-out alternate;
}
.box div:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0%;
  width:200%;
  height:160%;
  bottom:-10%;
  background:rgb(196, 3, 3);
  -webkit-mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="-500 0 1100 900"><path d="m 909.1,353.4 0,-67.6 c -70.8,0 -106.9,-14.7 -141.7,-29 -34.9,-14.3 -71,-29 -142.1,-29 -71,0 -107.2,14.8 -142.1,29 -34.8,14.2 -70.9,29 -141.7,29 -70.8,0 -106.9,-14.7 -141.7,-29 -34.9,-14.3 -71,-29 -142.1,-29 -71.1,0 -107.2,14.8 -142.1,29 -34.8,14.2 -70.9,29 -141.7,29 -70.8,0 -106.9,-14.7 -141.7,-29 -34.9,-14.3 -71,-29 -142.1,-29 l 0,632.2 1419,0 z"/></svg>') top/100% auto;
          mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="-500 0 1200 900"><path d="m 909.1,353.4 0,-67.6 c -70.8,0 -106.9,-14.7 -141.7,-29 -34.9,-14.3 -71,-29 -142.1,-29 -71,0 -107.2,14.8 -142.1,29 -34.8,14.2 -70.9,29 -141.7,29 -70.8,0 -106.9,-14.7 -141.7,-29 -34.9,-14.3 -71,-29 -142.1,-29 -71.1,0 -107.2,14.8 -142.1,29 -34.8,14.2 -70.9,29 -141.7,29 -70.8,0 -106.9,-14.7 -141.7,-29 -34.9,-14.3 -71,-29 -142.1,-29 l 0,632.2 1419,0 z"/></svg>') top/100% auto; 
   animation:waves .75s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes waves {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
@keyframes raise {
  from {
    transform:translateY(120%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div></div>
</div>
<div class="box" style="width:200px;">
<div></div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62579344/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>